# Longest increasing sequence of nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithm

Recently attended a MSFT interview for SDET position.. The 2nd round interviewer asked me this question:
Given a graph which has a number in the node value, find the set of all increasing sequence of vertices which are connected. Not able to recall the exact question.. The guy seemed very hostile and was refuting each of my solutions.. Any one knowing any such question.. Finally the solution was to have an adjacency matrix..
Still not sure how this will work..

Comment: I had proposed to start traversing from root node.. keep track of the linked neighbours.. if they form a sequence, remember them.. Also mark the root as visited... Do the same now for each of the root's connected verticies and so on and so on..                                                               He was ok to it but said think of it as patterns in an adjacency matrix..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step is to turn the bidirectional edges into directional edges, only going from the smaller to the larger numbered node for each one. Note that the resulting graph will be a directed acyclic graph (DAG), since we can't go from a small-high-small number in a path. From here on we can ignore the node numbering.

We have now reduced the problem to the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). The solution (described in detail in the link) is to perform a topological sort on the graph and then use dynamic programming to find the longest path.

All of this can be achieved in linear time.

Comment: @Saeed That's only true for general graphs, not DAGs. And my answer uses numbered nodes.

Comment: @Saeed: values in the nodes are trivially equivalent to values in the edges. But I don't see why we're talking about the longest path at all, since the question seems to be asking for *all* paths (including sub-paths).

Comment: @Beta I got that from the question's title, but rereading the question text I see where you come from. Finding all paths just requires a DFS.

Comment: I just read your last paragraph, and because I see some problems with answers like this (which are try to show P=NP) previously in `SO` I left the comment, yes longest path in DAG is p.